# Forecast.io using Time argument with JSONP not working

Tags: jsonp

My plan is to display the past 3 days of various weather stats to the user but I am unable to use the time argument properly. Here is my code:

```
var forecastURL = "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/API_KEY/".concat(lat,lng,new Date().toISOString().replace("Z","-72:00"));
                $.ajax({
                    url: forecastURL,
                    jsonp: "callback",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    success: function(response) {
                        console.log(response);
                    }
                });
```

I'm not sure I'm doing the date right but all I'm getting is a warning saying getDefaultPrevent is deprecated. Is something else at fault or is it just my date? If it's the date, what's the proper structure for manipulating ISO 8601 strings to look in the past? Preferrably 7 days if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, in this use `concat` does not return commas between the values, so my code below uses the `+ "," +` method rather than create another variable which is what you would need to do if you wanted to use concat.

Secondly, in ISO timestamps, ie:

```
2015-05-25T20:56:15.179Z
```

The `Z` means the UTC offset of the time is zero. This can be replaced by something like `+1000` for times in UTC + 10 hours. If you wish to change the time value itself then the UTC offset is not the place to do it.

```
var d = new Date();
d.setHours(d.getHours()-72);

var forecastURL = "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/API_KEY/" + lat + "," + lng + "," + d.toISOString();
//Your existing AJAX call would go here
```

You could replace `getHours` and `setHours` with `getDate` and `setDate` or any of the other JS date functions.

I can't test the JSON part of your question as I don't have an API key but it looks like it should work. Find some more info about JSON in jQuery [here](https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/).

Comment: Hi @Chase if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.